# Is it possible to change vim's underline symbol?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Now i am use VIM's ALE plugin which can underline the error in my code.
I set this `highlight ALEError cterm=underline` to underline the error with '-'.

I still want to use '^' instead of '-' which is much more eye-caching for me.So can anyone help me?I have been searching google for a while but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a caret. According to `:help attr-list`, the possible values for `cterm` are:

- `bold`
- `underline`
- `undercurl`, not always available
- `strikethrough`, not always available
- `reverse`
- `inverse`, same as reverse
- `italic`
- `standout`
- `nocombine`, override attributes instead of combining them
- `NONE`, no attributes used (used to reset it)

Comment: Thank u! I had read this part of vim doc, seems like the '-' is what i can do best for now.